# How to start the actual "Speech to text"?

Tags: ibm-watson, speech-to-text, transcription

I am a freelancing author and have gathered tons of hours of interview material which needs to be transcribed.

While browsing the Internet I came across IBM Watson "Speech to text" which should be the ideal solution to handle that huge amount of spoken word.

After registration I am struggling with even opening it. Since I am not very much equipped with programming, etc.

Can someone provide an example with steps that I can follow to achieve my task?

Answer (score 0):

which platform you want to use Speech to text service on it ?

Comment: What does "platform" imply in this context? My primary working equipment is an Apple MacBook with the latest OS

Comment: Hi Ahmed, I was just talking to IBM and it seems that without IT background and given my status being a small company this is not the right solution. But thanks for reaching out.

Comment: that is not my meaning ... i ask you want to use Speech to text service on Android App , Web App , Flutter App ... ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not a coder, then the best starting point for you will be Node-RED. Take a look at this tutorial that creates a translator - [https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/build-universal-translator-nodered-watson-ai-services/?cm_mmc=IBMDev-*-Digest-*-ENews2019-_-email&spMailingID=39408813&spUserID=MzYzODEwODAwNzk4S0&spJobID=1500992192&spReportId=MTUwMDk5MjE5MgS2](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/build-universal-translator-nodered-watson-ai-services/?cm_mmc=IBMDev-_-Digest-_-ENews2019-_-email&spMailingID=39408813&spUserID=MzYzODEwODAwNzk4S0&spJobID=1500992192&spReportId=MTUwMDk5MjE5MgS2)

If uses Speech to Text, Translation, and Text to Speech. You will only need the Speech to Text bit. Once you get it working with a microphone you can make use of the file inject to push your own audio files through the service.

For larger files you will need to make use of http post and multi-parts, when you get to that point, raise a new question, tag it with node-red and someone will post a sample flow for you.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have any programming knowledge to use Watson Speech To Text. You can just send your files to the service using the `curl` tool. Which you can easily install in your computer, it is free.

Then you can send a file to the service running the following command:

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}" --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --data-binary @audio-file2.flac "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"
```

You just need an apikey to run that command, which you can get following these steps: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/watson?topic=watson-iam

Then just replace the `.flac` file in that command by the file you want to process. And pass the right value for the `Content-Type:` header. For Flac files it is `audio/flac`, for other audio formats you have the list here: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text